# TypeError when defining Python code to access lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

```
data_set_01=[['A', A, 2, 'D'], ['A', T, 7, 'Y'], ['A', 2, 5, 'X']]
def draw_icons(data_set):
    for value in range(len(data_set)):
        if value[0] == "A" :
            icon1() ## Draw icon1.
        elif value[0] == "B":
            icon2() ## Draws icon2.
        elif value[0] == "C":
            icon3() ## Draws icon3.
        elif value[0] == "D":
            icon4() ## Draws icon4.
draw_icons(data_set_01)
done()
```

I'm trying to define a function that utilises a data set (a list in a list) where if the first variable inside the lists, lists is "A" to run the predefine code (in this case they should all be "icon1()". But instead it just comes up with a

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looping over a `range()`:

```
for value in range(len(data_set)):
```

so `value` is set to an integer in that range, starting at 0. You cannot then use indexing on that integer, so `value[0]` doesn't work.

Just loop over the `data_set` directly to get the nested lists:

```
for value in data_set:
```

Now `value` is bound to each of the nested lists, and `value[0]` will get the first element of those.

Instead of using `if` statements, you could use a dictionary to map letters to functions:

```
def draw_icons(data_set):
    icons = {'A': icon1, 'B': icon2, 'C': icon3, 'D': icon4}
    for value in data_set:
        if value[0] in icons:
            icons[value[0]]()
```

`icons` stores function objects, and retrieving them from the dictionary lets you call those functions.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over a range object which contains integer values, so you can not index them (as the error says).

I think you want to iterate over `data_set` :

```
for value in data_set:
```